# Is there a SQL Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I swear I saw a Stack Exchange site for SQL type questions a few months ago, but now I can't seem to find it. Was I on smoking something or is the almighty Google just not finding it for me?

Comment: Yes, it's right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql

Comment: Thank you all for helping me find the forum that I was looking for!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ask SQL Server Central](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/)? It's built on one of the SO clones, OSQA.

I remember another one at sqlteam.com but that appears to have gone, and http://ask.sqlteam.com/ redirects to SQL Server Central now.

Comment: I think it may have been this one, because I have an account there already. Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that we can link up our stackoverflow account with this one though.

Answer (score 4):

We've had a site for [database administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com) a while, though it's possible that it didn't exist at the time of the original question (nor had anyone updated it in the interim).

While it's not the site OP was likely thinking of at the time, it's probably the 'specialist' SE site they should consider.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you saw this SE1.0 site http://sqla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No, I don't believe so. I'm beginning to think that I was smoking something indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you were thinking of [Server Fault](http://www.serverfault.com)? It's a site for system administration, and sometimes gets SQL questions.

Comment: Nah, it wasn't Server Fault. I took a look at it and it didn't strike me as a forum that I'd have ever used for SQL questions. Thanks for the suggestion though.